# sinewave input input induction motor

Tags: motor, induction-motor, sine

If we put for standart 3 phase induction motor sinewave voltage input,
will we get sinewave current if we measure motor current with osciloscope.
At least sinewave like current ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ideally the currents will be sinusoidal. There may be some distortion, but look at the equivalent circuit of an induction machine.

[image]

There's nothing non-linear there in steady-state so the current should be sinusoidal. The phase relationship with the voltage will depend on the power factor resulting from the equivalent impedance at the operating point.  Of course transient loads will cause non-sinusoidal transient currents.

Comment: thanks a lot . So transient load usually is only a couple of seconds. Then we go bacvk to sinewave current (perhaps a little distorted).

Comment: Correct.  The winding method and physical construction details of the machine can cause some harmonics, but ideally the steady-state current is sinusoidal.

Comment: so i can make resonance in motor :      series or parallel      and to remain only active resistance. i mean to fully compensate inductive resistance . Then there will be only active/ohmic resistance of the windings (in steady state) ? thanks.

Comment: It's common to use capacitors to improve the power factor of an induction motor, though the PF is load dependent: http://www.ijettjournal.org/volume-4/issue-7/IJETT-V4I7P138.pdf

Comment: So when power power factor is 1 (or close to 1 like 0.98, 0,99) , there will be only ohmic resistance of the coils/wires of the motor. All the inductive resistance will be compensated/eliminated through capacitors. Like with resonant LC circuit ?

Comment: Yes, unity power factor is a purely resistive load.

Comment: many thanks. In brief in case of PF 1 we have only pure ohmic resistance of the coils of the motor.

Comment: Not exactly the ohmic resistance of the coils, but the resistive component of the equivalent circuit at the given operating point.  It's not the same thing that you would measure across the windings.